# Retrieving Values of Json Data Inside JSON Array in Mysql

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I have `JSON` column,  containing the JSON array. My Scenario, is to get all the the records where value of `url` is 
`'"example.com/user1"'` is present. I have trouble writing the query for this operation.

```
Record1
 [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "firstname": "user1",
        "url": "example.com/user1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstname": "user2",
        "url": "example.com/user2"
    }
]
Record2
     [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "firstname": "user3",
            "url": "example.com/user3"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "firstname": "user2",
            "url": "example.com/user2"
        }
    ]
......
......
......
Record10
     [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "firstname": "user10",
            "url": "example.com/user10"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "firstname": "user1",
            "url": "example.com/user1"
        }
    ]
```

The Query Which I ran is:

```
Select internal_id from users_dummy where JSON_EXTRACT(user_friends, '$[0].url') = "example.com/user1" or JSON_EXTRACT(user_friends, '$[1].url') = "example.com/user1";
```

So o/p was:
`Record1, Record10`

Is this the proper way to search for the values across the records?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the JSONString in in a column on your table defined as JSON type?

Comment: Provide a fiddle (or CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) instead of data example. All fields except JSON field may be skipped.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes !! The searchable JSON String is in a JSON column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_dummy 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(user_friends, 'one', 'example.com/user1', NULL, '$[*].url') IS NOT NULL
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fce158b9fba268eaca86297646f9b7cc)

You can use the following solution in case you are using objects instead of arrays:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_dummy 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(user_friends, 'one', 'example.com/user1', NULL, '$.*.url') IS NOT NULL
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1c2f38d5e0976cc955673388789818a)

Comment: Works !! Can you add 
How can the query change if we change the Record structure into json_object of objects rather than json_array of objects ??
example : 
`{
    "1": {
       "firstname": "user10",
       "url": "example.com/user10"
    },
    "2" : {
       "firstname": "user1",
       "url": "example.com/user1"
    }
}`